# How to hyperlink two different columns using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

So I've been trying for ages to try and get this working however I have only been able to get one column to use hyperlinks so far and when I look at the If and Else statement it makes no logical sense as to why its working.

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
print '<table><tr>';
foreach($row as $name => $value) {
print "<th>$name</th>";
}
print '</tr>';
while($row) {
print '<tr>';
foreach($row as $value) {
if($value['MobileNumber']){print "<td>$value</td>";}
else{print "<td><a href='/Test.php?MobileNumber=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
//else{print "<td><a href='/Test.php?TeamGroup=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
}

print '</tr>';
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
print '</table>';
```

I thought the else and if should be swapped around to make logical sense but it doesn't work if I do that. If I was able to get it working logically I could then put my second column as an Elseif and get it to work. How can I correct this?

I would ideally like it to look something like this.
I would like it to be able to do two columns of hyperlinks instead. So something like:

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
if($key!='MobileNumber'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?MobileNumber=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
elseif($key!='TeamGroup'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?TeamGroup=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
else{print "<td>$value</td>";}}
```

However putting this output all columns to have hyperlinks for /Test.php?MobileNumber=$value

Managed to get it working by using the following:

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
if($key=='MobileNumber'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?MobileNumber=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
elseif($key=='TeamGroup'){print "<td><a href='/Test.php?TeamGroup=$value'>$value</a></td>";}
else{print "<td>$value</td>";}
}
```

Comment: This question is a bit unclear. Can you share some sample data and show exactly what result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I read you question 5 to 6 times dont know what you are asking. Update your question. with the result which you are getting. and explain Whats wrong with that outcome. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting it to display one column with hyperlinks however I'm trying to get it to display two columns with hyperlinks. Those columns being MobileNumber and TeamGroup.
To me it feels as though the else and if statements should be flipped around however it doesnt work if I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the column name you need to examine.
In a foreach loop the syntax is

```
foreach($associative_array as $key=>$value){
    ...
}
```

so in this case you should change your code to

```
foreach($row as $key=>$value) {
    if($key!='MobileNumber'){
        print "<td>$value</td>";
    }else{
        print "<td><a href='/Test.php?MobileNumber=$value'>$value</a></td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Check my post i've written how id like it to look :)

Comment: Ah thank you, I used the $key=>$value and got it to work